# How can I add a disable class to a single select, not all of that I have

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to put a disabled class into my select, but when I do this:

```
$("input").attr("disabled",true);

//I tried to to this but it didn't work too:

$("#myId").attr("disabled",true);
```

It disable all of my selects and not one.
How can I disable only "myId"?

Comment: Please provide your HTML part.

Comment: By "select" do you mean a dropdown?  If so, it's a `select`, not `input`.  But if it's not working with `$("#myId")` it would suggest that the control doesn't exist in your html in the first place (make sure you use the same case)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML (which at the time of writing has not been supplied) it's very difficult for us to tell you why it's not working.

However, if `$("#myId").attr("disabled",true);` isn't working, then it suggests to me that you do not have an element in your HTML with `id='myId'`.

Things to check in the **rendered HTML** (as seen by the browser, not your code)...

- Is there an element with an `id` of `myId`
- Is the `id` exactly `myId`, and not `myID` for instance (as the case is important)
- Are you using something like ASP.Net where naming containers could be changing the `id` of the rendered control to something like `ctl00_myId`
- Do you have 2 elements with an `id` of `myId`... in which case, this is invalid HTML, as each element must have a unique `id`, and would result in jQuery only setting the `disabled` on the first item

Answer (score 0):

It disables them all because `$("input").attr("disabled",true);` adds the attribute disabled to all input elements. Without seeing your HTML it's hard to tell what the reason is for it not disabling when you try using `#myId`

Here are some mistakes I've made in the past for similar problems:

1) I did not actually have the `id` on the element that I thought I had. Whether it was a misspelling, or capitalization difference, or underscore vs dash...the point is the `id` I was trying to reference on the page simply did not match the one I was looking for with jQuery

2) I referenced it as an `id` but really it was a `class` or vice versa. `.` for classes, and `#` for id's is second nature, but sometimes if you're tired or exhausted you can very easily make that mistake

3) I had given an `id` that existed in multiple elements. `id` is supposed to be unique by convention. Duplicate id's will produce unexpected behavior

Hopefully one of these simple reasons is the cause for your issue and you can quickly resolve it. Maybe take a 30 minute break and come back to it.